# StringBuffer declaration and initialization showing error in Java

Tags: java, netbeans-8, stringbuffer

I am working with `StringBuffer`. Using `NetBeans 8.1` IDE.

Code I wrote:

```
package stringbuffer;

import java.lang.*;

public class StringBuffer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer("hello");
    }
}
```

But this is showing error like this:

[image]

**What's my problem?**

Comment: That's because `StringBuffer` is an actual Java class, and your IDE is confused.  Change the name of your class to something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've named **your** class `StringBuffer`. So it ***shadows*** `java.lang.StringBuffer` (and you never have to `import java.lang.*`). Rename your class, or use the fully qualified `StringBuffer` name.

```
public class StringBuffer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       java.lang.StringBuffer sb=new java.lang.StringBuffer("hello");
    }
}
```

**or**

```
public class MyStringBuffer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer("hello");
    }
}
```